# Are delegate methods privately declared?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, delegates

In my view controller's `viewDidLoad` method, I create an `NSURLConnection`

```
NSURLConnection *theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest 
                                                               delegate:self]
```

You can see I set the delegate to `self`.

Then I implemented the delegate method

```
-(void) connection: (NSURLConnection*) connection didReceiveResponse: (NSURLResponse*) reponse {
   //myImplementation;
}
```

This implementation is only defined in the `@implementation ViewController  @end` block, and it is not declared in the `ViewController`'s  `@interface`.

So I guess this method is private? It compiles and runs well. But I just can't call this method like `[self connection: connection didReceiveResponse: response]` in the `ViewController`'s own methods.

What's the explanation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The methods are declared via your inclusion of the [`NSURLConnectionDelegate` protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) in the class's interface definition:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <NSURLConnectionDelegate>
```

This tells the compiler that your class promises to implement all the required methods of that protocol, and that it may implement the optional methods (as it happens, this particular protocol has *only* optional methods). So the declarations exist publicly, they're just in another file.

Comment: It sounds like the OP is forgetting the protocol conformance declaration. He should be getting a warning on the initializer, although it looks like older versions of iOS declared the parameter as `id` instead of `id<NSURLConnectionDelegate>`, so it depends on what SDK he's using.

Comment: @Kevin: Yes, I had that impression too.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. I just checked ViewController class interface, and it actually didn't include teh protocol

Answer (score 2):

The method is "private" inasmuch as it is possible to have a private method in Objective-C. You actually can call the method from outside of the class, even if it's not declared in the interface. This is possible by way of Objective-C's dynamism in how it handles method calls -- any object can receive any message (the obj-c lingo for method), but whether or not the object can actually do something with that method depends on any number of things. Check out [Object Messaging](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocObjectsClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH11-SW1) in Apple's docs.

The short answer is that your code works as you have it because an implementation of your method exists in your class, and Objective-C knows how to find it at runtime regardless of your class interface.

Comment: @shredding: You should accept Josh's answer instead. This answer is right in that there's no such thing as a private method in Obj-C, but your real issue was the lack of protocol conformance. Declaring that you conform to the protocol will enable you to call the method directly, and it's the protocol that documents what methods `NSURLConnection` is looking for.